# Convert Mysql procedure into PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure on my Mysql DB, but i need to change it to get it done by PHP.

I've been looking around here and i know that is possible to make a SP from PHP, but it requires Mysqli (i don't have it updated, and updating it is not possible for personal reasons) or at least that was the only way i found to do it ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)).

So for me that only have Mysql, it's possible to do it from php? or should i just "translate" the procedure into PHP format? I mean not making a procedure but a function instead (php function), that actually do the same with PHP code (loops, selects, calls and so) but not storing the procedure on the DB.

This is my procedure

```
DELIMITER //

create procedure autor_products (in id int)
begin

update authors set authors_products= 
            (SELECT DISTINCT count(products_id)
FROM products
INNER JOIN authors_to_manufacturers as am ON am.manufacturers_id = products.manufacturers_id
WHERE authors_id = id)
WHERE manufacturers_id = id;

end
//

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE authors()

   BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
      DECLARE manu_length int;

      select max(manufacturers_id) into manu_length from authors;

      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;

         call autor_products(a);

         IF a >= manu_length THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

commit;
```

I managed to do this, which is "working" for at least one update

```
<?php

require('includes/configure.php');  //To get the DB name, user and pass
require_once (DIR_FS_INC.'xtc_db_connect.inc.php');  //I use this to connect the DB

$conn = xtc_db_connect() or die('Unable to connect to database server!');

$manu_lenght="select max(manufacturers_id) from authors;";


for ($i = 0;$i<=$manu_lenght;$i++){  //"for" not in use nor not working if i replace 1 for $i

$update= " update authors set products_amount = (SELECT DISTINCT count(products_id)
FROM products
INNER JOIN authors_to_manufacturers as am ON am.manufacturers_id = products.manufacturers_id
WHERE authors_id = 1)    
WHERE manufacturers_id = 1;"; 
} //will only update 1 author with authors_id = 1 so i needed to make a loop, but if i replace 1 for $i. it doesn't update at all

$retval = mysql_query( $update, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
?>
```

How may i use the $i variable instead of a specific number? (so it would update all at once because of the loop)

Edit: My manu_lenght is not working (it doesn't show the result of the select) but i just changed that part into a number and it's still not working, any thoughts?

Edit 2: Why is this code not working? It works if it's only $a=1; but not if i loop or make a bucle of $a.

```
$a = 1;
do{
$update= " update authors set products_amount = (SELECT DISTINCT count(products_id)
FROM products
INNER JOIN authors_to_manufacturers as am ON am.manufacturers_id = products.manufacturers_id
WHERE authors_id =$a)
WHERE manufacturers_id =$a;";
echo $a;
$a++;
}
while($a <= 10);
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting any errors? use `mysql_error` to access them. (and do find a way to switch to mysqli or pdo. there are reasons why it is deprecated)

Comment: @Burki I got no error messages, it says that its sucessfully updated, but still do not update. I just need to know why the loop is not working on the update.

Comment: have you tried printing out your generated query? Plus, you might want to check `mysql_affected_rows`, since an update with a condition that matches no rows would still be successful.

Comment: on a related note: are you sure you have both authors and manufacturers with the desired IDs, and those really match in the way you want?

Comment: @Burki I checked all the sql part, it was good, that only thing that was not working was the loop function, i just solved now, see my answer.

Comment: it seems i have to admit i was blind :-) Well done for solving it yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries i got what i need.

This is my code:

```
<?php


require('includes/configure.php');
require_once (DIR_FS_INC.'xtc_db_connect.inc.php');

$conn = xtc_db_connect() or die('Unable to connect to database server!'); 

//getting the total amount of authors into $manu_lenght variable
$manu_lenght = mysql_query("select max(manufacturers_id) as sum from authors;"  );


if(!$manu_lenght){
    die("DB query failed : " . mysql_error());
    $sum = "";

} //needed to fetch the result of the select query 
while ( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($manu_lenght)){
    $sum = $result["sum"];
}
do{
    $author_update= " update authors set products_amount = (SELECT DISTINCT count(products_id)
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN authors_to_manufacturers as am ON am.manufacturers_id = products.manufacturers_id
    WHERE authors_id =$a)
    WHERE manufacturers_id =$a;";

    $a++;
    //while was here, so that's why it wasn't working
    $ret_author = mysql_query( $author_update, $conn );
}
while($a <= $sum);  //now is correct, it sends the query now

if(!$ret_author )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated authors successfully\n";

?>
```

What i was basically doing wrong is ending the loop too early, and not letting the `mysql_query` function send the query (update in this case)

Instead of calling the procedure, i did the procedure translation through PHP. Hope this is useful for anyone else.